# how to set excel default margin for printing

Tags: excel

I need print different excel files daily with no top margin. I can change the margin manually each time in "page setup" (print preview), or "margins" (page layout). I hope I can set it as default so I don't have to do it every time for each file. There is some instruction about setting it as default when you create a new excel file, while I need it for existing files (to be open). 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The margin settings are saved with the file so if you are opening existing files you will have to change the margin settings each time. Probably creating a macro to apply the new margin would be the easiest way to do this.